# Import and split large-sized PDF poster into multiple A4 sheets

Tags: pdf, posters

I have some large sized PDF posters of varying dimensions. Is it possible with Latex to import each PDF and slice it into multiple A4 pages, so that when printed out and glued together, I basically get the original poster?

I guess I would need to calculate how many A4 pages fit vertically and horizontally across the original poster and then slice it in a nested loop or something. But I don't know how to do that or which package could provide the requested functionality. Any advice?

Comment: For any debian-related-distro, [it's really simple](http://askubuntu.com/a/697094), for Mac, [adobe reader](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/121886/136563), for instance, can do it. [Briss](http://briss.sourceforge.net/) seems to do the job on any platform. Why would you want LaTeX to do that?